# Bootstrap progress bar is not showing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using this code for a progress bar and it's working fine on my laptop and on other desktop devices but in mobile view progress bar is not showing:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="progress ">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"  aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="0" style="width:0%">
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row progress-row"><div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align:    left;">$0</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">$29,000,000</div></div>                    
                       ICO STARTS IN 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `col-sm-6` classes to `col-6` to prevent the labels from stacking on the smallest screens. The progress bar itself is showing up as expected on the smallest screens.

Click the "run code snippet" button below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="0" style="width:0%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row progress-row">
       <div class="col-6">$0</div>
       <div class="col-6 text-right">$29,000,000</div>
    </div>                    
    ICO STARTS IN 
</div>
```